# Best books for a population-ecology and biology statistics

Tags: biostatistics, genetics, ecology

I know that there is question that's similar to this ([Books on statistical ecology?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70526/books-on-statistical-ecology)). I've got recommendations from that, but want to ask you for an advise following this list of books:

*1. Applied Statistical Genetics with R: For Population-based Association Studies (Use R!) Andrea S. Foulkes 2009*

*2. Mathematical Population Genetics 1: Theoretical Introduction (Interdisciplinary Applied Mathematics) (v. 1) Warren J. Ewens 2004*

*3. Ecological Models and Data in R Benjamin M. Bolker 2008*

*4. A Biologist's Guide to Mathematical Modeling in Ecology and Evolution Sarah P. Otto 2007*

*5. Practical Computing for Biologists Steven Haddock 2010*

*6. Dynamic Models in Biology Stephen P. Ellner 2006*

*7. The R Book Michael J. Crawley 2012*

My work is likely to assume tasks like analysis of genetic sequences, assessment of biological diversity and other.

I am good at applied math and programming and also know basics of population biology and genetics.
Could anyone recommend me 2-3 books of your choice or just say what would be more useful for me?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

P.S. I wanted to add links on every book for convenience, but i have no enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the classic Numerical Ecology, Legendre & Legendre; Numerical Ecology with R., Borcard et al. [available for free download](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio/R_eng/Numerical%20Ecology%20with%20R%20(use%20R).pdf); Analysis of Ecological Communities, McCune and Grace; vignettes for packages used in your specific field (eg [Zhao's *gap*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gap/vignettes/gap.pdf)). Considering that diversity is a community-level property, I'd encourage you to look at community ecology lit, not just population level. Once you decide on the models you want to use, there are more theme-specific texts out there, and not necessarily from ecology or genetics.